# Sp_BlitzCache 678 not writing to table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sp-blitzcache

Version 678 from github is displaying results in SSMS query window as expected but not creating a table, using the following commands:

```
USE DBAResources;
GO
EXEC dba.sp_BlitzCache @Top=10, @OutputDatabaseName = 'DBAResources', @OutputTableName = 'dba.BlitzCacheResults';
```

BlitzCache is compiled as stored procedure dba.sp_BlitzCache in database DBAResources. Note the use of the non-dbo schema for the stored procedure and the table.

Running on SQL Server 2016 SP 1 Standard.

Comment: You could look to https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit. Use Merge pull request #681 from BrentOzarULTD/issue_299/brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pop open sp_BlitzCache, you should see parameters for:

```
@OutputDatabaseName NVARCHAR(256) = NULL ,
@OutputSchemaName NVARCHAR(256) = NULL ,
@OutputTableName NVARCHAR(256) = NULL ,
```

You seem to have tacked the schema name onto the table name. That's probably what's causing the problem.